# Coursera's google queries joins

Tags: join

Am working on google Coursera's need little help with the join part big query for bank International Education found  6. In the Search Marketplace search bar, type international education.
7. Click the first result, The World Bank's International Education dataset.
8. Click View Dataset. This will bring you back to the BigQuery Sandbox interface in a new tab.
● Note: You may want to star the bigquery-public-data dropdown to the Explorer menu. You
can use this to browse datasets and tables without navigating to the data marketplace in the
future.
. In the Explorer menu, search for world_bank_intl_education. Click the dropdown arrow to expand
the dataset. You may also need to click on the SHOW MORE button for the additional subsets to
appear
and did all this
10. Click the international_education table. This will bring up the table’s schema. If the schema
doesn’t appear, click on the Schema tab in the table viewer.
11. Next, select the country_summary table and examine its schema. You’ll find that the country_code
column appears in both the table schemas and I did this too
Thank I enter the Query
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table_1 INNER
JOIN table_2 ON
table_1.key = table_2.key;

trying to get help on the query because I'm not doing it right